# PCF Login issue from cli

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

I am new to PCF. I registered with trail version.
I am trying to login via cf login command in Windows by using command prompt, powershell, gitbash. 
I am always getting ' credentials were rejected '
please help to get resolved.

Comment: @K.AJ - I believe you have that backwards. CMD & Powershell should work fine, the known issue with `cf login` impacts Cygwin & git bash. See the first item here -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli#known-issues

Comment: @Jai - Please run `cf -v login` and try again. Include the full output here. That should show more detail about what is happening.